# Ремаппинг поискового expression tree при наличии вложенной лямбды

Tags: c#, automapper, expressions

Я использую Automapper и трехуровневую архитектуру в приложении. У меня есть метод, который принимает `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate` в качестве параметра. Чтобы передать этот параметр с нужным типом `Т` на другой уровень я делаю ремаппинг. Я создал `ExpressionExtension class`, который используется для возврата преобразованного `Expression`:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class which contains extension methods for <see cref="Expression"/> and <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> instances.
/// </summary>
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remaps all property access from type <typeparamref name="TSource"/> to <typeparamref name="TDestination"/> in <paramref name="expression"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source element.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type of the destination element.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result from the lambda expression.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression">The <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> to remap the property access in.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="Expression{TDelegate}"/> equivalent to <paramref name="expression"/>, but applying to elements of type <typeparamref name="TDestination"/> instead of <typeparamref name="TSource"/>.</returns>
    public static Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>> RemapForType<TSource, TDestination, TResult>(
        this Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        Contract.Requires(expression != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>>>() != null);

        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDestination));
        Contract.Assume(newParameter != null);

        var visitor = new AutoMapVisitor<TSource, TDestination>(newParameter);
        var remappedBody = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        if (remappedBody == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to remap expression");
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDestination, TResult>>(remappedBody, newParameter);
    }
}
```

И код для AutoMapVisitor:

```
/// <summary>
/// An <see cref="ExpressionVisitor"/> implementation which uses <see href="http://automapper.org">AutoMapper</see> to remap property access from elements of type <typeparamref name="TSource"/> to elements of type <typeparamref name="TDestination"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source element.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type of the destination element.</typeparam>
public class AutoMapVisitor<TSource, TDestination> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly TypeMap _typeMap;
    private readonly List<TypeMap> _typeMaps = new List<TypeMap>();
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, ParameterExpression> parameterMap = new Dictionary<Type, ParameterExpression>();
    private Dictionary<MemberInfo, Expression> memberMap = new Dictionary<MemberInfo, Expression>(); 

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="AutoMapVisitor{TSource, TDestination}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newParameter">The new <see cref="ParameterExpression"/> to access.</param>
    public AutoMapVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        _typeMap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();
        Contract.Assume(_typeMap != null);
        _typeMaps.Add(_typeMap);
        _typeMaps.AddRange(FillNestedTypeMaps(_typeMap));
        parameterMap.Add(newParameter.Type, newParameter); // main parameter which we don't need to recreate
        foreach (TypeMap map in _typeMaps)
        {
            if (parameterMap.ContainsKey(map.DestinationType)) continue;
            parameterMap.Add(map.DestinationType, Expression.Parameter(map.DestinationType, map.DestinationType.Name.ToLower()));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// находим все возможные маппинги текущей конфигурации вниз по иерархии свойств класса источника
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tMap">Объект конфигурации, содержащий информацию о типе источника и типе назначения</param>
    private IEnumerable<TypeMap> FillNestedTypeMaps(TypeMap tMap)
    {
        List<TypeMap> result = new List<TypeMap>();
        // 1 where: маппинг только между классами
        // 2 where: маппинг не равен входящему и ReverseMap значению, например на входе: A -> B, тогда отпадут значения A -> B и B -> A из проверки
        // 3 where: берем те свойства, тип которых совпадает с входящим типом источника или, если это обобщенный тип, с его аргументом и тоже самое для типа назначения
        IEnumerable<PropertyMap> pMaps = tMap.GetPropertyMaps();
        var list = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps()
                         .Where(
                             map => map.SourceType.IsClass && map.DestinationType.IsClass)
                         .Where(map =>
                                !(map.Equals(tMap) ||
                                  (map.SourceType == tMap.DestinationType && map.DestinationType == tMap.SourceType)))
                         .Where(
                             map =>
                             pMaps
                                 .Any(
                                     pi =>
                                         {
                                             var pis = pi.SourceMember as PropertyInfo;
                                             if (pis == null) return false;
                                             bool forSource = pis.PropertyType == map.SourceType ||
                                                              (pis.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                                                               pis.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == map.SourceType);
                                             bool forDestination = pi.DestinationPropertyType == map.DestinationType ||
                                                                   (pi.DestinationPropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                                                                    pi.DestinationPropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == map.DestinationType);
                                             return forSource && forDestination;
                                         }))
                         .ToList();
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            result.AddRange(list);
            foreach (TypeMap typeMap in list)
            {
                result.AddRange(FillNestedTypeMaps(typeMap));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Type Map(Type type)
    {
        var tMap = _typeMaps.FirstOrDefault(map => map.SourceType == type);
        Contract.Assume(tMap != null);
        return tMap.DestinationType;
    }

    private ParameterExpression Map(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        var mappedType = Map(parameter.Type);
        ParameterExpression mappedParameter;
        if (!parameterMap.TryGetValue(mappedType, out mappedParameter))
            parameterMap.Add(mappedType, mappedParameter = Expression.Parameter(mappedType, parameter.Name));
        return mappedParameter;
    }

    private Expression Map(MemberInfo mi, Expression exp)
    {
        Expression val;
        if (!memberMap.TryGetValue(mi, out val))
        {
            foreach (PropertyMap propertyMap in
                         _typeMaps.Select(map => map.GetPropertyMaps().SingleOrDefault(m => m.SourceMember == mi))
                                  .Where(propertyMap => propertyMap != null))
            {
                memberMap.Add(mi, val = Expression.PropertyOrField(exp, propertyMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo.Name));
                break;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Visits the children of the <see cref="T:System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The modified expression, if it or any subexpression was modified; otherwise, returns the original expression.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="node">The expression to visit.</param>
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var expression = Visit(node.Expression);
        if (expression == node.Expression)
            return node;
        return Map(node.Member, expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters.Select(Map));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return Map(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        // if static object and generic method
        if (node.Object == null && node.Method.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            // Static generic method
            var args = Visit(node.Arguments);
            var genericArgs = node.Method.GetGenericArguments().Select(Map).ToArray();
            var method = node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(genericArgs);
            return Expression.Call(method, args);
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Теперь после ремаппинга кидает `Exception`:

variable 'person' of type 'Reestr.DAL.Entities.Person' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Любопытно, что данное исключение бросается только в том случае, если у нас есть в наличии вложенная лямбда, к примеру:

```
Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>> a = val => val.FullName == "ABC" && val.SomeEnumerableProperty.Any(inner => inner.City == "Moscow");
```

Если же мы просто наполнили поисковый LINQ запрос обычными свойствами:

```
Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>> a = val => val.FullName == "ABC";
```

то всё работает хорошо, исключение не бросается. Похоже на то, что отсутствует какая-либо ссылка на объект либо где-то как-то был создан ещё один параметр, но я не могу понять где (наверное при ремаппинге внутренней лямбды). Какие могут быть предложения по решению. Благодарю!

Comment: Скопируйте текст вопроса целиком, не заставляйте людей ходить по ссылке

Comment: @PashaPash, понял, а переводить нужно?

Comment: да, иначе набегут закрывающие